# Is there a way to calculate a P-Value for a T-Statistic in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I realized that this is outside of the Salesforce wheelhouse, but can anyone help?

I have a custom class that determines the t-static from a series of pairwise tests.  I have a requirement to calculate the p-value for the particular t-statistic and degrees of freedom.

I am looking for a function similar to the Math3.TTest (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/inference/TTest.html) function in Java.  Is anyone familiar with a similar function in Apex or do they know of how to write one without an established Continuous Distribution Function?